# Variavel em Clojure

Tags: clojure

Eu gostaria de ter um contador em memória. Uma variável que em qualquer momento eu posso adicionar ou subtrair e quando eu quiser eu acesso o valor atual dela.

Como fazer isso em Clojure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma maneira simples é usar um `atom` para manter o valor atual:

```
(def cnt (atom 0))
(doseq [i (range 5) ]
  (swap! cnt inc)
  (println "value=" @cnt))

value= 1
value= 2
value= 3
value= 4
value= 5
```

Veja http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom
e http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/swap!

Comment: Traduza para o portugues

Comment: era exatamente o que eu precisava, vlw!

Comment: Gostaria de chamar atenção, que Clojure, vem da ideia de imutável, ou seja, por mais que exista a função `atom`, a utilização dela acaba fugindo do escopo.